# Vary Color of Object Based on Object Dimensions (Size)

Tags: shaders

I have a DNA model that I created and imported from a 3D chemistry modeling program (Avogadro). I exported the model in .wrl format (the only 3D format allowed for export by Avogadro) and imported into Blender. Unfortunately, there's a bug in Blender 2.8x that does not allow color to be imported in .wrl format.

So, I need a workaround. I need to color each molecule a different color based on its object dimensions. For example, the phosphorous molecule is a particular size as are carbon, oxygen, nitrogen, and hydrogen. I've spent a few hours now scanning the various forums for an answer. I have yet to find a solution.

Ideally, I'd also like to color the little stick bonds between each atom based on the colors of the two atoms it is binding together. That's not a deal-breaker, though. I can get away with making the stick bonds a single color.

See the attached images for the shader setup I have right now and the result it's producing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The node tree above works if your objects have a "scale". In your case it seems they all belong to the same object and has the scale applied. Is this the case. BTW, if there is a bug in 2.8x, can't you import the model in a working release (2.79?) and then copy paste it in 2.8x?

Comment: Hello, is this one object containing all the meshes, or are each sphere individual objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close - you just need to swap one of your `Math` nodes for a `Vector Math` node, and the other for a `MixRGB`. Note the divide factor for the mix node is set to 1 (anything less covers less than the whole surface).  See below:

[image: ColBySize]

NOTE - The scale I had initially was too big, apparently, I had to scale all the objects down (except for the empty) to get it to look right, but I was working fast and carelessly. I'm sure it can look "right" at any scale, it may just have to be adjusted by adding a `Map Range` node between the `MixRGB` and the `ColorRamp` - Just connect the color output of the `MixRGB` to the value input of the `Map Range`.